# We can only use a blockingqueue or any other data structures for Threadpool task queue?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

Hi I am a newbie in Concurrent programming with java. of all the examples I saw in concurrent programming whenever we use to define a task queue people used different implementations of blockingqueue.
why only blockingqueue? what are the advantages and disadvantages?
why not any other data structures?

Comment: Way too broad - suggest you read the first few chapters of a book e.g. Java Concurrency In Practice.

Comment: thanks for the answer slim..yes it is too broad of a question..I just wanted to get an idea why is it so.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i can't address exactly why unspecified code you looked at uses certain data structures and not other ones. But Blocking queues have nice properties. Holding only a fixed number of elements and forcing producers who would insert items over that limit to wait is actually a feature.

Limiting the queue size helps keep the application safe from a badly-behaved producer, which otherwise could fill the queue with entries until the application ran out of memory. Obviously it's faster to insert a task into the task wueue thsn it is to execute it, an executor is going to be at risk for getting bombarded with work.

Also making the producer wait applies back pressure to the system. That way the queue lets the producer know it's falling behind and not accepting more work. It's better for the producer to wait than it is for it to keep hammering the queue; back pressure lets the system degrade gracefully.

So you have a data structure that is easy to understand, has practical benefits for building applications and seems like a natural fit for a task queue. Of course people are going to use it.

Comment: thanks for the answer Nathan. I got an overview or idea why is it so... :)